# Call a YUI function from HTML

Tags: html, function, yui

i have the Dial example from the official YUI website and its awesome. I have the function in a JS file and works perfectly but i want to call it inside the html page with some parameters (like the value, min, max, etc), but nothing works.

The dial function is this:

```
YUI().use('dial', function(Y) {

    var dial = new Y.Dial({
        min:-220,
        max:220,
        stepsPerRevolution:100,
        value: 30
    });
    dial.render('#demo');

}
```

Thank you so much!

EDIT: I'm going to write a very very simple C++ code and i think you will understand exactly what i want:

```
int a = 3;int b = 4;
example (a, b);

a=2;b=4;
example (a, b);

void example (a, b){  //this shoud be the dial function in a JS file
    int c = a + b;
    cout << c; 
}
```

As you can see, i'm printing C every time i call "example" and specifying the values i want every time i call it. If I call example 8 times, it will print the C variable 8 times. That's what i want with the Dials. I want to call as many times as i need the function that creates the Dial from the HTML page with the parameters i need, and the function will create the Dial with those parameters. I dont know if that's possible, but i need this so thank you for help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should include something like this:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.7.3/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>  
<script>
YUI().use('dial', function (Y) {
    var dial = new Y.Dial({
        min:-220,
        max:220,
        stepsPerRevolution:100,
        value: 30
    });
    dial.render('#demo');
});
</script>
```

Is that not working for you?

Edit: Adding another example per the discussion in comments. You could do something like this instead:

HTML File:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.7.3/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>  
<script>
    var dialConfig = {
        min:-220,
        max:220,
        stepsPerRevolution:100,
        value: 30
    }
</script>
<script src="/path/to/initialize-widgets.js"></script>
```

initialize-widgets.js File:

```
YUI().use('dial', function (Y) {
    var dial = new Y.Dial(dialConfig);
    dial.render('#demo');
    // possibly do more setup work after this... 
});
```

Comment: Yes, thats working perfectly but i have that function in a JS file and i want to be able to call it from my HTML page with the values i want. If i can do that i can create one dial each time and call the function but changing their values every time i call it.

I'm spanish so i don't know if you can understand me, sorry :) and thanks a lot for reading and for your help

Comment: Since YUI().use(...) creates a sandbox, you cannot call code inside the sandbox from anywhere else, unless you assign to global variables attached to window.  It's better to just inline the code.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you're saying a little better now. So if you're *just* creating different dials on different pages (with different config parameters, I would follow John Lindal's advice and keep the 'var dial = new Y.Dial({...})' code inline. However, if you need to write some larger chunk of YUI code that you want to reuse across multiple pages, you should look into creating a YUI module using YUI.add(). See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/#yuiadd -- you can stick the YUI.add() code in a separate file, and call YUI.use() to use it in an HTML page.

Comment: The YUI module option seems interesting but i think thats usefull when you are trying to have one module prepair to use in a lot of different pages, but that's not exactly what i want.

I need a "module" (or function or something like that) that allows me to create as many dials as i want to, just calling that "module". For example, i want 8 dials with different config parameters, but i dont want write the dial function every time, i want to write it just 1 time and call that function 8 times specifying the parameters i want, it's that possible?ly. Thank you so much for reading and helping.

Comment: Hi there, I've added another example which might be more along the lines of what you are asking for. Here, we 1) load YUI, 2) define a global variable (just on that page) with specific Y.Dial configurables, then 3) pull in a separate 'initialize-widgets.js' script that instantiates the Dial (and maybe does other work), using the dialConfig variable. Here you just need to specify specific config values in the page, and the other script files do the rest. Caution -- the dialConfig variable is a global variable.

Comment: Hi Evan, first of all thank you so much for helping me :) I saw what you wrote and it seems interesting, but that creates me as many dials as i want but always with the same parameters, because i'm using directly the global variable "dialConfig" and i want to be able to pass parameters to the function you create in "initialize-widgets.js". I want that "initialize-widgets.js" to be always the same file and, every time i call it, i can create a new dial with the parameters i'm specifying on the calling. I'm going to edit the first post to be more specific.

Comment: Satyam already answered me in yui forums, so thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't call JavaScript code from your HTML.  Instead, you listen to events happening in the HTML and respond to them.

For example, let's say you have this:

Show Dial

Then what you do is:

```
Y.one('#go').on('click', function () {
    var dial = new Y.Dial({
       min:-220,
       max:220,
       stepsPerRevolution:100,
       value: Y.one('#value').get('value');
    });
    dial.render('#demo');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but i think that's not exactly what i need.